# Iterate a Complex Collection and find whether the value is again a collection C#

Tags: c#, api, c#-4.0, loops, collections

Please provide your inputs on the below scenario,

For instance, I have a collection - **Dictionary** which has some 10 items. Each item can be a simple key value pair / the value can again be a any of the following like Hashtable[] / String[] / DataTable / a custom type / a custom type[] / Dictionary / Array List etc.

I should iterate the collection until the value is a simple key value pair indefinitely. Please let me know the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This may be enough for you

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, object> pair in dictionary)
{
    if (pair.Value.GetType().IsValueType || pair.Value is string)
    {
        // do something
        break;
    }
}
```